# How Can find total height remain of a container in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i make a kitchen layout with the help of drag and drop. If i select layout of 10 X 10 for kitchen, have to make some validation in that area. suppose i drop a 5x5 wall on to that area then how to find what height and width remains and where it place vartical or horizontal...

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming about your kitchen layout and wall

```
<body>
    <div class="kitchen">
         <div class="wall">
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The above should be a prototype of your html

Now use:

```
var wallHeight = $('.wall').height(); // Gives wall's height
var wallWidth = $('.wall').width(); // Gives wall's width
var kitchenHeight = $('.kitchen').height(); // Gives kitchen height
var kitchenWidth = $('.kitchen').width(); // Gives kitchen width
var leftHeight = kitchenHeight - wallHeight, 
    leftWidth = kitchenWidth - wallWidth; 
// Gives remaining width and height
```